# Can a check made out to 2 people be deposited into a non joint account?

Tags: banking, joint-account

Can a check made out to 2 people be deposited into a non joint account?

I have a check made out to myself and another person My bank will not allow e to deposit it into my personal account and there is no way to set up a joint account at this time.  What can I do or is there a bank that will allow me to set up a joint account without both people being present?

Comment: Just have John and Sue both endorse the check. Then deposit it.

Comment: Can you ask the maker to redo the check? That seems much easier than making a joint account.

Comment: Is the check endorsed by both parties?

Comment: The answer to this may be different depending on your location / jurisdiction. Could you add a country tag or comment so that someone can add it for you? For example, I know US and UK differ in this.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: It depends...

### How has the check been made out?

Three possible variations:

Either party:

```
Pay to the order of
Mr. John Doe OR
Mrs. Jane Doe
```

Both parties:

```
Pay to the order of
Mr. John Doe AND
Mrs. Jane Doe
```

Ambiguous:

```
Pay to the order of
Mr. John Doe
Mrs. Jane Doe
```

In the first case, you should be able to deposit the check in either person's individual account, or a joint account. In the second case you will have to deposit in a joint account OR bring the other person with you to the bank and have them show their ID to the cashier and endorse the check in their presence. In the third case it could go either way (I've been able to cash checks written like that into my individual account, but your mileage may vary).

### Jurisdiction

From your spelling of check (vs. cheque) I'm assuming you're in the USA, where endorsing checks is a thing. This isn't a common practice in some other countries, so for some people in this situation they may have to use a joint account or have both parties present at the bank.

### Bank Policy

Your bank also has discretion over whether or not to cash the check just for you in each of the three variations shown above. A small local credit union for example may know you and the other payee personally and be a little more relaxed about cashing/depositing the check versus a national financial institution with many branches and cashiers that have never interacted with you before. The bigger institutions are much less likely to deviate from their official policies on the matter, mainly to protect themselves from potential litigation.

Your best bet is to ask your bank how you can cash the check if you don't have a joint account. They should be able to give you some options, or may direct you back to the payer to request a check written in a different format.